# NodeJS Thrift Missing First Row

Tags: node.js, hbase, thrift

I am using the Thrift NPM library for Node.js for a project I am working on.

**When i run the following scan using the Hbase shell i get 1 result (correct):**

```
scan "UserLog", {COLUMNS => ["entry"], FILTER => "(SingleColumnValueFilter('entry', 'addedTime', >=,'binary:1437696000000',true,true)) AND (SingleColumnValueFilter('entry', 'addedTime', <=,'binary:1437764400000',true,true))"}
```

**Using NodeJS Thrift with the same scan (in the Node format) I get no result (incorrect):**

```
var query = { columns: [ 'entry' ], filterString: '(SingleColumnValueFilter('entry', 'addedTime', >=,'binary:1437696000000',true,true)) AND (SingleColumnValueFilter('entry', 'addedTime', <=,'binary:1437764400000',true,true)) ' }
```

**The NodeJS Thrift code we are using is:**

```
this.connection.hbaseConnect(function(client, connectionHbase) {
if(client) {
    client.scannerOpenWithScan(tableName, new _hbase_types.TScan(query), null, function (err, scannerId) {
        client.scannerGet(scannerId, function (err, result) {
            client.scannerGetList(scannerId, 1000, function(err, res){
                if(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
                callback(res);
                connectionHbase.end();
            });

        });
    });
}
else
{
    callback(false);
}}, Message);
```

Our environment details are:

- We are using Hbase 0.98.1.
- NodeJS Thrift Package can be found here - https://www.npmjs.com/package/thrift